# Creating a Deck Class extending Stack

Tags: java, stack, extending

first of all let me say that this is not so much a question of how to get it to work, it is more a question of whether this is good practice or not.

I want to implement a deck of cards (As seen in a lot of games, for example TCG games), with a custom shuffle() method... For now it uses a standard library method, but that may change in the future.

The code:

```
package model;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 *
 * @author Frank
*/
public class Deck<T> extends Stack<T> {
    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(this);
    }
}
```

Current code where I use it:

```
private Deck<Card> deck;
```

Just wondering if this is good practice, eager to hear answers.

Comment: I don't like java's built in `Stack` because it is just an extension on top of `Vector`...

Comment: Consider `Deque` instead of `Stack`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not good practice. Your `Deck` class should **contain** a `Stack`, it should not **be** a `Stack`.

I'm not sure you want `Stack` anyway. It is more likely you want `ArrayList<Card>` or something like it.

Comment: I agree, I am afraid I have overlooked it. However I think a Stack is definately better as you push and pop, which is not possible with an ArrayList

Comment: A decent card-sharp should be allowed to deal from either end of the deck, or even the middle - thus the `ArrayList` :) You could try a `LinkedList` if you are worried about performance. All you really need to state is that it **contains** a `List` of `Card`s.

Comment: Oh... I was trying to use stack.get(i) , that would've been a guaranteed failure?

Answer (score 0):

I'd better use delegation instead of inheritance here. Extending a stack makes you stuck with it forever, while delegation will let you replace a stack with something else easily.

Additionally, it is generally not best practice to extend collections. Java 8 would introduce a lot of new things to collections which could break you implementation or your logic.